# Coverity. Configure to ignore certain sections of the source code(Python)

Tags: python, coverity

Ask how ignore certain sections Python code in Coverity scan.
C/C++ uses # to hide code snippets, but how to hide python code snippets.
The following is C/C++ ignore certain sections #ifndef **COVERITY**.